# How do i auto scroll in swiftui?

Tags: swiftui

I am not able to autoscroll down when the component loads.
i tried every chatgpt trick there is haha.

I tried to implement this but could not figure it out::
https://udaypatial.medium.com/scroll-to-bottom-of-a-list-of-items-swiftui-21ade9f2d46b

```
import SwiftUI


struct ChatEditView: View {
    @State private var chat_id: String? = nil
    @State private var message: String = ""
    @StateObject private var chat_service = ChatService()
    @AppStorage("user_data") var user_data: Data?

    init(chat_id: String? = nil) {
            self._chat_id = State(initialValue: chat_id)
        print("PASSING IN",chat_id)
        }
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            
            if chat_service.messages.count > 0 {
                     ScrollView {
                         ScrollViewReader { scrollView in
                             VStack {
                                 ForEach(chat_service.messages.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                                     ChatBubbleCardView(
                                         message: chat_service.messages[index].message,
                                         is_current_user: calculate_is_current_user(message_created_by: chat_service.messages[index].created_by,
                                                                                    user: chat_service.messages[index]
                                         )
                                     )
                                 }
                             }
                             .onChange(of: chat_service.messages) { _ in
                                 scrollToBottom(scrollView)
                             }
                         }
                     }

                 } else{
                Text("Loading")
            }

        }
        .navigationBarTitle("Chat", displayMode: .inline)
        .onAppear {
            print("ChatEditView loaded")
            print("chat_id: ", chat_id)
           handle_get_chat_messages()

        }
    }
    
    func scrollToBottom(_ scrollView: ScrollViewProxy) {
         guard !chat_service.messages.isEmpty else { return }

         let lastIndex = IndexPath(item: chat_service.messages.count - 1, section: 0)
         withAnimation {
             // Scroll to the bottom
             scrollView.scrollTo(lastIndex, anchor: .bottom)
         }
     }

    func handle_get_chat_messages() {

        if chat_service.manager.status == .connected {
            chat_service.get_chat_messages(chat_id: chat_id!) { messages in
//                    self.chat_messages = messages
            }
        } else {
            chat_service.manager.defaultSocket.on("connect") { _, _ in
                chat_service.get_chat_messages(chat_id: chat_id!) { messages in
//                        self.chat_messages = messages
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The goal is for the component to load, the chat messages to load, and then scroll down

Comment: For a start, the `ScrollView` should be inside the `ScrollViewReader`, not the other way around. See the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/scrollviewreader) for more clues on getting it working, or try searching SO (instead of asking ChatGPT).

Comment: You will also likely need to place an `.id(index) onto your `ChatBubbleCardView`, otherwise the `ScrollViewReader` won't know what view you are referring to.

Comment: What I did in my own code is to add `Spacer().frame(width: 1, height: 1).id("end of list")` just after the `ForEach(...){...}` 
and then have  `scrollView.scrollTo("end of list")` in the `.onChange...`. Make sure each `ChatBubbleCardView(..)` in your ForEach 
has a `.id(string)`

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/scrollviewreader